# C++0X when?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will C++0x be finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436139/when-will-c0x-be-finished)

What are the latest news about C++0X? (or should I say C++1X) Any release date decided yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### UPDATE : years later...

The last Draft have been officially finalized few weeks ago, in Mars 2011 and will be officially out around July 2011. The name of the new standard would be C++2011 : http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/

Microsoft C++ compiler (VC10) provide C++0x features (lambda, decltype, auto, r-value reference and nullptr). GCC provide a work in progress version that already implements a lot of features (see http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).
Comeau C++ seems to be more advanced. CLang started to provide some features but not much for the moment (see http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html )

So, most of the features are be availables for the main c++ compilers at the time the ISO administration officially validate the draft. Some advanced features are still not be available before some years I guess.

Answer (score 8):

It's unlikely that this committee draft will become the FCD.  I would say there will be at least 2 more meetings of the standard committee before it goes to FCD.

I think there is something like a 1 year lag between the FCD and the actual standard, so it could be 2011 (or even later!!!)

Comment: +1 for getting it right.  :-)

Comment: +1 and **wow** for the foresight - did you have a crystal ball around?

Answer (score 3):

A new [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) came out recently, so things are progressing. From this draft to the finalized version, it should be no more than a year before things are finalized. I should note that this draft is the feature-complete version; from here on it should only be revisions. I was just made aware, however, that the path from draft to actual, published, standard is a very long road. I'll push my estimate of a published, accepted standard out to 2010.

How long until we have full compiler compliance? That is a different story. GCC is making good progress on the language features that aren't libraries (see [list of features they have implemented](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)), but has no mention of progress on the concurrency features. I can't say anything for when MSVC/dinkumware/whatever other compilers you may use will start implementing things like lambda.

Boost already has much of TR1 implemented, and dinkumware has it all, so you can start using the new libraries already (maybe not in their final form, however).

Answer (score 3):

A number of free and commercial compilers already include support for certain C++0X features.

- [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html): static_assert, strongly typed enums, variadic templates...
- [Codegear C++Builder 2009](http://www.codegear.com/products/cppbuilder/whats-new/): static_assert, strongly typed enums...
- [Visual C++ 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en): mostly TR1 support

As for when the standards committee actually publish, well...

Comment: Gcc ( http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html ) and Visual C++ ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en ) have C++0x features.

Comment: Yeah, but the two that I'm really interested in (`auto` and native lambdas) aren't in there yet. :-(

Comment: Head Geek: GCC 4.4 (the unstable development trunk) has auto, and the lambdas branch works fairly well (no return type deduction though).

Answer (score 1):

The committee recently issued a Committee Draft, which will become a Final Committee Draft, which will become a Final Draft International Standard, which will become ISO 14882:20xx, giving an expected publication date of sometime at the end of 2010.

However, GCC 4.3 and later implement increasingly larger subsets of C++0x, and other compiler developers are already working on implementations (none are available yet that I know of).