# When will C++0x be released?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [C++0X when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226061/c0x-when)
> [When will C++0x be finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436139/when-will-c0x-be-finished)

When will [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) be released? Anyone here know anything?

Comment: Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x for everyone like me who had no idea what c++ox was.

Comment: This have already been asked and answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226061/c0x-when#229072

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**: We have a new standard now : http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/

---

**Edit**: The FDIS is done, so officially it should be released in few months.  See : http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/

---

Herb Sutter is a useful source of information on this as the convener of then ISO C++ committee (until recently).

**EDIT**
See his latest blog post [here](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/) from March 13, 2010 for an update on recent progress: C++0x is now a Final Committee Draft, and...

*"... assuming all goes well , C++0x could officially be published as soon as next year as ISO C++ 2011, and we can stop with the “x-is-hex” jokes and just start calling it C++11."*

P.J. Plauger has taken over as the new convener, but I expect that Herb will continue to provide updates on the committee's progress - and as Herb also works for Microsoft, early clues as to when a Microsoft implementation of C++0X will be available.

Comment: UPDATE: http://herbsutter.com/2010/08/28/trip-report-august-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/- There will be a vote on March 21, 2011- if it succeeds, then the standard is in place.

Answer (score 4):

The deadline is **2009**.

Comment: only because then it will be renamed 1x if it runs into 2010.

Comment: Hmm, at a conference 1 year ago, Bjarne Stroustrup joked on it that the `x` in `C++0x` may be in hexa...

Comment: @Piotr: His idea was C++0B, But I think C++0xB looks much nicer, as 0B looks like an incorrect octal number to me... but 0xB is perfectly formed hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

As stated on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x :

> The ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21 C++
>   Standards Committee aims to introduce
>   the new standard in 2009 (hence the
>   standard that is today called C++0x
>   will become C++09) which means that
>   the document must be ready for
>   ratification of the member states of
>   ISO in 2008. To be able to finish on
>   schedule, the Committee decided to
>   focus its efforts on the solutions
>   introduced up until 2006 and ignore
>   newer proposals [1].