# Learning about C++ 0x features

Tags: c++, c++11

What is a good place to learn about the new C++ 0x features? I understand that they may not have been fully finalized yet but it would be nice to get a head start. Also, what compilers currently support them?

Comment: Not a duplicate but you could get some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226061/c0x-when) There are both links to drafts and a list of compilers that are implementing C++[0|1]x features

Comment: Partial Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200237/where-can-i-learn-more-about-c0x . It doesn't talk about the compiler support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An easy and fun way to learn about it is to watch the [C++0x Overview Google Techtalk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JffvCivHEHU). Another good source is Bjarne Stroutstrup's [C++0x FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html) which covers a huge portion of the new features.

Answer (score 3):

For VC++2010, here's the list of things that will be there.

Language (some of these were in VC2008 already as language extensions):

- lambdas
- `static_assert`
- `auto` and `decltype`
- rvalue references (`T&&`)
- `nullptr`
- `extern template` (note: not `export`!)
- `long long`
- no space required between closing `>` in nested templates (e.g. `vector<vector<int>>` is legal)

Libraries:

- `<stdint.h>` / `<cstdint>` and all the typedefs within (at last!)
- `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`
- `std::forward_list`
- `std::tuple` and associated things (e.g. `tie`, `get`...)
- `<system_error>`
- `<type_index>`

What is **NOT** there:

- initializer lists (curiously enough, header `<initializer_list>` is there and contains the respective type, but there seems to be no language support for it in beta 2)
- variadic templates
- `constexpr`
- range-based `for` (though language extension `for each`, which is mostly similar, remains)
- uniform initialization syntax `{}`
- alternative function syntax (that mimicks lambdas)
- constructor delegation
- same-line member field initializers
- `[[override]]` (but `override` remains as a language extension)
- `=default` and `=delete` on members
- `enum class`
- `using` for type aliases, and template `using`
- `char16_t` and `char32_t`, and the corresponding string literals
- raw and user-defined string literals
- `sizeof` on instance fields without object instance
- `std::thread` and friends

Comment: A link to the source would be great!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215(VS.100).aspx covers language features. There's also a series of blog posts, though they're somewhat outdated now (e.g. they claim no `nullptr` support, even though it is now there):  http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/04/22/decltype-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-3.aspx

Comment: As for the library, I can't find any definite document covering this. I compiled the list above by looking at what is provided in my VS2010 beta 2 install. Also note that the list above doesn't include library features that were present in TR1, and that were simply moved from `std::tr1::` to `std::` for C++0x (VC2010 supports such features in both namespaces).

Answer (score 3):

For compiler support you can look here : [C++0xCompilerSupport](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport).

Compilers:

PAPER(S)
HP aCC
EDG eccp
gcc
Intel C++
MSVC
IBM XLC++
Sun C++
C++ Builder 2009/10

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly know about the official working group web site for [ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/).  This has the committee information, so it contains the official documents that are under development.  However, it is not necessarily the best place to learn about the background ideas behind the various suggested ideas for C++0x.

Another place to look is the [comp.std.c++](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/) news group; this often has esoteric discussions of the minutiae of possible features.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about the language features but you might want to take a look at [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1). It's a specification of libraries that will most likley make it into C++0x.

There are actual implementations for it so you can play with it right now (for example a [VC++ implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/01/08/q-a-on-our-tr1-implementation.aspx) by Microsoft).